# Boot-Repair --- recovering Ubuntu after installing Windows 8

Tags: boot

I would like to recovere Ubuntu after installing Windows 8. I have installed boot repair to recover grub but after reebot it does not show up grub.

The url after running boot-repair is [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7139616).

Comment: Note my URL after installed boot-repair is (http/paste.ubuntu.com/7139616). any help ?

Comment: I didn't see any ext4 partition, did you installed Ubuntu via wubi?

Answer (score 0):

When you install Windows, it thinks it is the Only operating system on your computer so it replaces GRUB with it's own boot-sector. Try upgrading ubuntu from a live USB or CD. It had worked for me with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Good Luck !